# Html #footer doesnt show up

Tags: html, footer

So I would just like to say that I have been studying web-development mostly self thought but I did go to school for a year for it as well, Now, on to my problem, so I am designing a simple website design and I am trying to get the footer to show up, but I cant seem to make it work I've been messing around with it and it just doesn't seem to want to work.
Here is the code

```
          #footer
      {
        background-color: black;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      p
      {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

   </style>
   <body>

       </div>
      </div>
     <div = id "footer">
     <div class = "container">Copyright Notice</div>
     </div>
```

Yes I did cut out a part that wasn't necessary and it made the question look really weird, Sorry for my grammar, English isn't my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in HTML. There has to be:

```
<div id="footer">
```

instead of

```
<div = id "footer">
```

Comment: Oh lord... Thank you so much, That happends alot to me, I get too into the code and then it ends up with me getting too close to the issue to actually solve it myself! Thank you!

Comment: Is there any button that gives some sort of reputation? I really appriciated your answer!

Comment: @Blade: there is a tick icon (accepted answer) under answer's score.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the HTML code you pasted is incomplete, as it begins with the closing of two `div` tags.

Discarding the two first lines, here's how your code should look like:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">Copyright Notice</div>
</div>
```

Notice that on the first `div` you had the `=` before `id`. HTML tags are composed of a tag name and optional space-separated properties and their respective values as in this example:

```
<tagname property1="value1" property2="value2>Content</tagname>
```

Having spaces around the `=` won't break your code in most situations, but it's not a good practice.

Comment: I fixed the issue, And yes, the code I posted I did cut out a pretty big chunk of code, If you would like the full code I could send it.